# VS Code hover preview not working properly

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, hover, preview

I have been using VS Code for java for quite some time now, but I recently switched to the insiders version. Using settings sync all the settings and extensions were automatically integrated into that version, and everything seems to work fine, except one small thing in the java extension.

See, java itself works just fine, debugging, compiling, syntax highlighting or replacing, but the preview has a bug. When I hover over let's say a method, it does show the description, but in the top line where it normally shows the full name of the variable or method, e.g. `somePackage.SomeClass.aMethod(): void` it just says "java". Anywhere, where this should show up this shows up instead.
Has anyone an idea how to fix this as anything else seems to work just fine? Maybe it has to do with the insiders edition? On the regular version it (that was not uninstalled) it still works fine.

Comment: It may just be this bug:  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961740/836330

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the print statement as an example. When we hover over the `println`:

What VS Code shows is like you say, the full name of a method:

[image]

VS Code Insider shows the Title **Java** and its function description:

[image]

The [Insiders build](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/05/23/evolution-of-insiders) is designed for early adopters wanting a nightly release. In fact, Insiders builds are the builds for internal used to develop VS Code. With Insiders build, Production group can get valuable feedback and usage insights prior to each Stable release. There's no way to make the preview in Insider as the same as VS Code. It's still recommended to use **VS Code** during daily development.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, but why would the insiders version show something different here? Especially where this is an extension?

Comment: That's because they're facing different using objects. Insider is for internal developers to develop more stable version, if this function is stable enough, it will be applied in stable version, which is vs code. Now, there're some functions only existing in Insider and waiting to be tested and applied. so you don't have to be bothered by this.

Comment: So I think Insiders is like a beta-version of Code. Do you mean that they show „java“ in that place for debugging purposes? I can’t think of any other reason. Even if you were to develop vs code using this, there really isn’t a point in that - you want that for developing

Comment: yes,Insiders is the beta-version of Code. the title **java** has no real function to debug but is more likely to be a statement to show the current language is java then description or docs follow.