# VS Code only displays 1 row of possible import paths. How do i convert back it to default listbox?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I think I made some setting changes in vs code which made my import statements look like this.

[image: Missing list box of possible import paths]

The default VS code import preview shows 3 or more paths.
What would be the option I should change to revert it back to the default list box view?

[My settings.json](https://gist.github.com/iandjx/28e34dbfec2ffba8a9a8d21e03024c51)

Comment: if you completely empty your global and workspace settings file do you see what you want

Comment: There is a `Reset Suggestion Widget Size` command or try dragging the bottom edge of the box down to increase its height.

Comment: Oh wow. I just had to drag he bottom edge. thanks Mark! could you convert your comment to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last vscode update to v1.51 added the ability to change the size, height and width, of the suggestion box.  It also seems to have set the box height to one lineHeight for some people.  There is a command in the command palette to reset the suggestion widget's dimensions:

`Reset Suggest Widget Size` that should fix your situation.

You can also drag the lower boundary of the box down (or the right edge left and right) to change its dimensions.

The old setting that set the suggest widget's height to some user-defined number of entries (I believe the default was 12) is now gone.  If you change its height or width (as well as the width of the extra info flyout box connected to the suggestion widget) that change should be remembered.